# Is there a way to ignore a field when writing history table with @Customizer

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipselink

I have a class which is annotated with eclipselink `@Customizer`.

That customizer, uses a custom customizer that inherits from `DescriptorCustomizer`.
In `customize` function I have a HistoryPolicy in order to create a history table for the annotated class.

Down below I leave an example:

Custom Customizer:

```java
public class MyCustomizer implements DescriptorCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ClassDescriptor cd) {
        HistoryPolicy policy = new HistoryPolicy();
        policy.addHistoryTableName("history_table");
        policy.addStartFieldName("start_ts");
        policy.addEndFieldName("end_ts");
        cd.setHistoryPolicy(policy);
    }

}
```

My Class:

```java
@Entity
@Customizer(MyCustomizer.class)
public class myClass {
    @Column(name = "field_To_Track")
    private Integer fieldToBeTracked;
    @Column(name = "field_Not_To_Track")
    private Integer fieldNotToBeTracked;
}
```

I want to ignore a fields from being the reason why a row it's written in the history table. That way, every new row written in the table it's not because of an update on that column. Is that possible?